# Make .htaccess work in a symlink target folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink

I use a symlink in public_hmtl to access scripts in a folder elsewhere on the server, but the folder has an .htaccess file that prevents access and the scripts won't work if I just remove/disable it.

The symlink is here:

/home/username/public_html/symlink

The script target folder is here:

/home/target

Is there a way to make that .htaccess file work in the symlink target folder? Or should I move it somewhere else?

I have tried adding this to the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

But that didn't do anything. Apparently I also have to put this somewhere (?) in Apache configuration:

```
    # enable allowoverride privileges
    <Directory /home/target>
        AllowOverride Options
    </Directory>
```

But my VPS is configured with EasyApache4, so I am not supposed to manually edit virtual host files and methods to include these line via WHM produced errors.

Should I keep trying FollowSymLinks/AllowOverride? Or is that a dead end anyway? Are there other solutions?

Apologies for my ignorance. .htaccess confuses the hell out of me. I have no clue what is going on it those files.

Edit:

The .htaccess file has these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteRule ^resetPassword$ /index.php?resetPassword=true
RewriteRule ^resetPassword/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?resetPassword=true&hash=$1

RewriteRule ^install$ /index.php?install=true
RewriteRule ^install/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?install=true

RewriteRule ^update /index.php?update=true
RewriteRule ^update/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?update=true

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?act=dashboard.show
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?act=$1.$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?act=$1.$2&id=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: That will depend whether those files are within the same ftp account or not, if they are then you can use some rewriterule otherwise you're better of having it within your ftp account path

Comment: Not really clear what the actual problem is here to begin with. This part, _“but the folder has an .htaccess file that prevents access and the scripts won't work if I just remove/disable it”_ needs a better explanation.

Comment: @Prix, yes, all files 'within the same ftp account'; they are all owned by the same Apache user and on the same server.. The script files are on a level below public_html. The symlink is in public_html, so I can access the script on mywebsite.com/mysymlink

Comment: @misorude, the symlink doesn't work if I leave the .htaccess in the target folder as it is; I get a white screen and then it reloads back to mywebsite.com. The symlink does work when I remove/disable .htaccess, but then the script doesn't work.